# How to export all the raw media from iMovie libraries?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, imovie

I have a couple of iMovie library files. I want to export the raw videos/photos outside of the library. I don't want to edit them or anything like that. Just having a copy outside of iMovie.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to your Movie directory
2. Right-click on *iMovie-Mediathek*
3. Left-click on "show package content"
4. And there you can find the raw data